# Intellisense for Visual WebParts (ASCX) and Custom Application Pages (ASPX) in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, application-pages, visual-web-part

How can I enable intellisense for visual webparts (.ascx) & custom application (aspx) pages in VS 2010? It would save me a lot of time!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the page in Solution Explorer, click Open With... and select whatever editor as at the top of the list that has (With Encoding) next to it.

Comment: I tried the following: 
- Right click my usercontrol
- Open with: "User Control with encoding"
- Encoding "Auto-Detect"

Still, it doesn't work. Any idea?

Thx!